# enable edit for cell field at row grouping level ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ag-grid, cellrenderer

I have created an ag-grid. where I am grouping the records as row grouping. In that grid, **one column is autocompleting typeahead drop-down column** I have used the below package to implement it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor
[image]

currently, it looks like this. since I have done the grouping I am unable to show typeahead col at group level. I want to autocomplete typeahead here for bulk (group level) update.

I tried multiple ways but unable to do it. I tried using aggFunc also unable to since I am using another package.
Which should return something like:

`cellEditor: AutoCompleteSelectCellEditor, cellRendererParams: {values: this.getData.bind(this)}, valueFormatter: ...`

I am unsure of how this will work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After googling for a couple of days. I found the solution.

We can achieve this by adding.

```
enableGroupEdit={true}
```

Also, At the column level, we need to add

```
editable: true
```

or

```
editable: {this.isCellEditable}
```

and we can have a function `isCellEditable(param)`  to enable editable dynamically based on requirements.

Comment: I believe editable: true needs to be added to the defaultColDef property, as editable: true on a particular column gets ignored. A colDef and it's auto-generated row-group column are treated differently. A colDef that is { editable: false, rowGroup: true } will still be editable in the row-group version of the column, when the defaultColDef.editable = true

Answer (score 0):

```
enableGroupEdit={true}
```

we can control which field to allow by calling a function that returns a boolean.

```
enableGroupEdit = {(params) => myfunction(params)}
```